# Error in displaying web pages using Flask

Tags: python, flask, web

I used flask to make a web portal for the users to register but when I run the html file using a local host, the display looks like below:

[image]

Comment: Post your python code which generates the following template. Are you running using `app.run(debug=True)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This html file is not actually an html file but rather a Jinja template. Thus, you need it to be served via your flask app render_template function. So it makes not sense to open this page via browser as html.